# How to get iterative output from a "for" loop in R shinyapp?

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I am looking for a solution in which we can print single iteration output in R shiny. Right now I got the output (a bunch of text output) when For loop ends its working. Is there any way to print itrative output to R shiny mainpanel from for loop ?

Edit 1. Here is a sample code I can not share original code due to official reason. Hope it helps.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "LAP"),
dashboardSidebar( 
sidebarMenu(
  #menuItem("Introduction", tabName = "intro", icon = icon("info-circle")),
  menuItem("test", tabName = "FD", icon = icon("info-circle"))

)),

dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "FD",
          fluidRow(
            box(verbatimTextOutput("loc") )))
  )
 )
)
 server =shinyServer(function(input, output){

 mydata<- reactive({

for(i in 1:100){

  print("For Demo Purpose")

}

})

output$loc<- renderPrint({
mydata()
}) 
})

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Include your code in your post :)

Comment: @kristang I added the demo code, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can think of would be to use the iterated function to append to a reactive variable, and display that variable in another output element.

Just keep output and generation separate. The output element will trigger a redisplay when the reactive value changes, but shouldn't cause odd loops to happen as long as it doesn't modify any variables.

Here's my initial attempt at an example, which doesn't work properly:

```
## stub UI with an activation button and text output element
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Iterative output demo"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("start","Start Program")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         textOutput("showProgressText")
      )
   )
)

## server stub
server <- function(input, output) {
   ## reactive list to store result values
   iterativeOutput <- reactiveValues();
   ## text rendering function `showProgressText`
   output$showProgressText <- renderText({
     sapply(iterativeOutput,paste);
   })
   ## iterative function; modifies the reactive list on each iteration
   observeEvent(input$start,{
     iterativeOutput <- reactiveValues(); # clear list
     for(i in 1:10){
       iterativeOutput[[as.character(i)]] <- 
         sprintf("%2d: For Demo Purpose\n", i);
       Sys.sleep(0.2);
     }
   })
}
```

This code outputs the modified information all in one go, rather than updating it.

I think the problem is likely to be that Shiny is waiting for the end of the function to check for reactive triggers. This is because, despite appearances, Shiny does not run operations in parallel. The only way to get two things working iteratively is to break the function, allow other functions to run, then resume the function. This is the process mentioned in the [Google groups link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/0ExyzzaaXTU).

The first implementation in that link works because a timer is set up to run one iteration of the function at one-second intervals. Here's an alternative implementation where the iterative function updates only [once] when a button is pressed:

```
## UI stub
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Iterative output demo"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("start","Start Program")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         htmlOutput("showProgressText")
      )
   )
)

## Server stub
server <- function(input, output) {
   iterativeOutput <- reactiveValues();
   output$showProgressText <- renderText(
       paste0(sapply(reactiveValuesToList(iterativeOutput),paste), 
              collapse="<br />\n")
   )
   observeEvent(input$start,{
     #iterativeOutput <- reactiveValues(); # clear list
     i <- (input$start-1) %% 10;
     iterativeOutput[[as.character(i)]] <- 
       sprintf("%2d: %d", i, sample.int(1000, 1));
   })
}
```

The `insertUI` approach is interesting, because it is creating a separate display loop in the middle of a method. I can imagine Shiny code becoming a lot less simple and predictable if that approach were used all over the place.

Comment: can you show this with demo code, I am not getting your point.

Comment: yes, certainly. I wrote this answer on a cellphone in transit from NZ to London, and had difficulty putting in example code. I'll update shortly.

Comment: For the user who are looking for the solution can go through this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/0ExyzzaaXTU